# How to delete file from SD Card after Mail send Successfully?

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to delete File from SD Card After mail sent successfully to Receiver.How to do this?I found a lot of here on SO as well as on Google.I tried as well.my code is as:

```
if(myFile.exists())
    myFile.delete();
```

with the above code i delete the file which is stored in SD Card before sending it to on Receiver side.Please someone help me for my this issue.Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What issues with this code are you experiencing? be detailed.

Comment: execute this code after sending mail.

Comment: when i write this code it deleting the file from sd card before attaching it to Mail.I want to delete that file which is stored in SD Card after Mail send Successfully to Receiver Side.Any Suggestion Regarding that?

Comment: @Robinhood: it gives me same problem.i already tried it earlier.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4609129/delete-file-after-sharing-via-intent

Comment: when you send mail success or even fail file will be deleted.. to hand le this type to use javamailAPi need think.. so

Comment: i am not getting any Error but my problem with the above code is that i am deleting that file before attaching it to mail.I want to delete that file from SD Card after Mail sent Successfully to Receiver.Any Suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

You receive Mail sending status on `onActivityResult`, so start intent with `startActivityForResult`..

here is sample code..

**Send Mail:**

```
int EMAIL = 101;

Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
emailIntent.setType("text/html");

emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,new String[]{});
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_BCC,new String[]{});
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, pngUri);
startActivityForResult(emailIntent,EMAIL);
```

**Sending Result:**

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(requestCode==EMAIL)
        {
            if(requestCode==EMAIL && resultCode==Activity.RESULT_OK)    
            {
                            if(myFile.exists())
                                myFile.delete();  
                Toast.makeText(mActivity, "Mail sent.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else if (requestCode==EMAIL && resultCode==Activity.RESULT_CANCELED)
            {
                Toast.makeText(mActivity, "Mail canceled.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else 
            {
                Toast.makeText(mActivity, "Please try again.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }   
    }
```

Comment: it sends me everytime in this condition i dont know why?f (requestCode==EMAIL && resultCode==Activity.RESULT_CANCELED)
            {
                Toast.makeText(mActivity, "Mail canceled.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else 
            {
                Toast.makeText(mActivity, "Please try again.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

Comment: thats mean your mail not sent sucessfull

Comment: actually when i send mail with only startActivity its sends successfully nut when i use startActivityforResult its sends me in that condition.i dont know why?]

Comment: what is the meaning of int EMail = 101?

Comment: 101 is request code, you can use any INTEGER number,,,reciver recieving mail ?

Comment: using email or gmail for sending msg ?

Comment: is it possible to get startActivityforresult in Email?i think its not possible for Email or MMS as well.

Comment: yes i am opening all default email like gmail,yahoo mail etc using intent.

Comment: use default email application... not gmail & yahoo

Comment: you dont have any idea about using Intents?

Comment: it will return in **onActivityResult** either mail sent or cancel. so you can delete your file in this method. remove all condition, if it is not working

Answer (score 0):

```
  file.deleteOnExit();
```

It will delete your  file when activity will be close. [check this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4609566/646806)

Or

Used Alarmmanager and set one time to delete your file after appropriate time, lets say after one hour or half an hour.

Answer (score 0):

when you open e mailbox according to activity life cycle your current Activity move on onPause() when you return in your activity then On Resume method will call so write the blow code on your on Resume method.

protected void onResume() {

```
    File file= new File(filepath);
    if(file.exists())
    {
         file.delete();
    }
    super.onResume();
}
```

here filepath is path of external storage or where you saved your file, which you wants to delete.