# How to delete image after full screen exit with getContentResolver().delete(uri, null, null);

Tags: java, android, image, share

I have my FullscreenActivity and after exit I want to delete the image it made.
With my code the picture is deleted before the sharing intent and so sharing is not working.

Plan B/QuestionB would be how can I save the picture with my code in it´s own folder instead of camera folder?

I hope you  have an idea.

```
    public class FullImageActivity extends Activity {



    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.full_image);

        // get intent data
        Intent i = getIntent();

        // Selected image id
        int position = i.getExtras().getInt("id");
        ImageAdapter imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(this);

        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.full_image_view);
        imageView.setImageResource(imageAdapter.mThumbIds[position]);
        BitmapDrawable bm = (BitmapDrawable) imageView.getDrawable();
        Bitmap mysharebmp = bm.getBitmap();
        String path = Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(),    
                            mysharebmp, "MyImage", null);
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(path);

        Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        sharingIntent.setType("image/*");
        sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent,
                            "Share image using"));
        getContentResolver().delete(uri, null, null);
        sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, Uri.fromFile(new File(path))));


    }

}
```

Comment: +1 for your question :)

Comment: dude just see this link may be this will help u http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4609129/delete-file-after-sharing-via-intent

Comment: thx :D

no it´s not working :(
tried: 
File tbd = new File(path);
tbd.deleteOnExit();